# Reconstruct full coordinate reference system stored in a GML file

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas, gml, osgeo

I have been able to parse a GML file and fetch the polygons I wanted. They can be plotted ok when plotted on their own. I have them stored in a
GeoPandas data frame, but I am struggling to set the proper `CRS` to be able to use this data along with other data frames in a consistent manner.

Each feature is like this

```
<omi:OMIFeature>
<omi:title>MyTitle</omi:title>
<omi:description>Descr</omi:description>
<omi:linkzona></omi:linkzona>
<gml:MultiSurface srsName="GEOPOIUTM32.5" srsDimension="2">
<gml:surfaceMember>
<gml:Polygon>
<gml:exterior>
<gml:LinearRing>
<gml:pos>520381.7 4648450.2</gml:pos>
<gml:pos>520435.9 4648293.8</gml:pos>
<gml:pos>520450.9 4648243.6</gml:pos>
... more positions like this
```

The specification of the CRS seems to be a custom one named `GEOPOIUTM32.5`

I did find a dictionary that seems to describe in full this coordinates reference system, but I am afraid I am not able to use this info. What info should I pick here and use it to set the CRS of this data frame with `set_crs()`? (I have tried 6402, 7030,4326 as `EPSG` but they give oddly placed results or not plot anything at all. I figured that 32633 gives x coordinate off by a huge amount, but y is nearly right).

```
<gml:Dictionary gml:id="OMI_Dictionary">
    <gml:description>Dictionary description</gml:description>
    <gml:name>Dictionary name</gml:name>
    <gml:dictionaryEntry>
        <gml:ProjectedCRS gml:id="ogrcrs104">
            <gml:srsName>GEOPOI / UTM zone 32.5</gml:srsName>
            <gml:srsID>
                <gml:name>GEOPOIUTM32.5</gml:name>
            </gml:srsID>
            <gml:baseCRS>
                <gml:GeographicCRS gml:id="ogrcrs105">
                    <gml:srsName>WGS 84</gml:srsName>
                    <gml:srsID>
                        <gml:name>4326</gml:name>
                    </gml:srsID>
                    <gml:usesEllipsoidalCS>
                        <gml:EllipsoidalCS gml:id="ogrcrs106">
                            <gml:csName>ellipsoidal</gml:csName>
                            <gml:csID>
                                <gml:name>6402</gml:name>
                            </gml:csID>
                            <gml:usesAxis>
                                <gml:CoordinateSystemAxis gml:id="ogrcrs107" gml:uom="urn:ogc:def:uom:EPSG::9102">
                                    <gml:name>Geodetic latitude</gml:name>
                                    <gml:axisID>
                                        <gml:name>9901</gml:name>
                                    </gml:axisID>
                                    <gml:axisAbbrev>Lat</gml:axisAbbrev>
                                    <gml:axisDirection>north</gml:axisDirection>
                                </gml:CoordinateSystemAxis>
                            </gml:usesAxis>
                            <gml:usesAxis>
                                <gml:CoordinateSystemAxis gml:id="ogrcrs108" gml:uom="urn:ogc:def:uom:EPSG::9102">
                                    <gml:name>Geodetic longitude</gml:name>
                                    <gml:axisID>
                                        <gml:name>9902</gml:name>
                                    </gml:axisID>
                                    <gml:axisAbbrev>Lon</gml:axisAbbrev>
                                    <gml:axisDirection>east</gml:axisDirection>
                                </gml:CoordinateSystemAxis>
                            </gml:usesAxis>
                        </gml:EllipsoidalCS>
                    </gml:usesEllipsoidalCS>
                    <gml:usesGeodeticDatum>
                        <gml:GeodeticDatum gml:id="ogrcrs109">
                            <gml:datumName>WGS_1984</gml:datumName>
                            <gml:datumID>
                                <gml:name>6326</gml:name>
                            </gml:datumID>
                            <gml:usesPrimeMeridian>
                                <gml:PrimeMeridian gml:id="ogrcrs110">
                                    <gml:meridianName>Greenwich</gml:meridianName>
                                    <gml:meridianID>
                                        <gml:name>8901</gml:name>
                                    </gml:meridianID>
                                    <gml:greenwichLongitude>
                                        <gml:angle uom="urn:ogc:def:uom:EPSG::9102">0</gml:angle>
                                    </gml:greenwichLongitude>
                                </gml:PrimeMeridian>
                            </gml:usesPrimeMeridian>
                            <gml:usesEllipsoid>
                                <gml:Ellipsoid gml:id="ogrcrs111">
                                    <gml:ellipsoidName>WGS 84</gml:ellipsoidName>
                                    <gml:ellipsoidID>
                                        <gml:name>7030</gml:name>
                                    </gml:ellipsoidID>
                                    <gml:semiMajorAxis uom="urn:ogc:def:uom:EPSG::9001">6378137</gml:semiMajorAxis>
                                    <gml:secondDefiningParameter>
                                        <gml:inverseFlattening uom="urn:ogc:def:uom:EPSG::9201">298.257223563</gml:inverseFlattening>
                                    </gml:secondDefiningParameter>
                                </gml:Ellipsoid>
                            </gml:usesEllipsoid>
                        </gml:GeodeticDatum>
                    </gml:usesGeodeticDatum>
                </gml:GeographicCRS>
            </gml:baseCRS>
            <gml:definedByConversion>
                <gml:Conversion gml:id="ogrcrs112">
                    <gml:coordinateOperationName></gml:coordinateOperationName>
                    <gml:usesMethod xlink:href="urn:ogc:def:method:EPSG::9807"/>
                    <gml:usesValue>
                        <gml:value uom="urn:ogc:def:uom:EPSG::9102">0</gml:value>
                        <gml:valueOfParameter xlink:href="urn:ogc:def:parameter:EPSG::8801"/>
                    </gml:usesValue>
                    <gml:usesValue>
                        <gml:value uom="urn:ogc:def:uom:EPSG::9102">12</gml:value>
                        <gml:valueOfParameter xlink:href="urn:ogc:def:parameter:EPSG::8802"/>
                    </gml:usesValue>
                    <gml:usesValue>
                        <gml:value uom="urn:ogc:def:uom:EPSG::9001">0.9996</gml:value>
                        <gml:valueOfParameter xlink:href="urn:ogc:def:parameter:EPSG::8805"/>
                    </gml:usesValue>
                    <gml:usesValue>
                        <gml:value uom="urn:ogc:def:uom:EPSG::9001">500000</gml:value>
                        <gml:valueOfParameter xlink:href="urn:ogc:def:parameter:EPSG::8806"/>
                    </gml:usesValue>
                    <gml:usesValue>
                        <gml:value uom="urn:ogc:def:uom:EPSG::9001">0</gml:value>
                        <gml:valueOfParameter xlink:href="urn:ogc:def:parameter:EPSG::8807"/>
                    </gml:usesValue>
                </gml:Conversion>
            </gml:definedByConversion>
            <gml:usesCartesianCS>
                <gml:CartesianCS gml:id="ogrcrs113">
                    <gml:csName>Cartesian</gml:csName>
                    <gml:csID>
                        <gml:name>4400</gml:name>
                    </gml:csID>
                    <gml:usesAxis>
                        <gml:CoordinateSystemAxis gml:id="ogrcrs114" gml:uom="urn:ogc:def:uom:EPSG::9001">
                            <gml:name>Easting</gml:name>
                            <gml:axisID>
                                <gml:name>9906</gml:name>
                            </gml:axisID>
                            <gml:axisAbbrev>E</gml:axisAbbrev>
                            <gml:axisDirection>east</gml:axisDirection>
                        </gml:CoordinateSystemAxis>
                    </gml:usesAxis>
                    <gml:usesAxis>
                        <gml:CoordinateSystemAxis gml:id="ogrcrs115" gml:uom="urn:ogc:def:uom:EPSG::9001">
                            <gml:name>Northing</gml:name>
                            <gml:axisID>
                                <gml:name>9907</gml:name>
                            </gml:axisID>
                            <gml:axisAbbrev>N</gml:axisAbbrev>
                            <gml:axisDirection>north</gml:axisDirection>
                        </gml:CoordinateSystemAxis>
                    </gml:usesAxis>
                </gml:CartesianCS>
            </gml:usesCartesianCS>
        </gml:ProjectedCRS>
    </gml:dictionaryEntry>
</gml:Dictionary>
```

Comment: That crs has essentially the same definition as UTM, but with the central meridian at 12, halfway between zones 32 and 33. So you can try setting the crs with a custom string, like a proj string: `+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=12 +k=0.9996 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs` or with a WKT, take any one of the WGS84 UTM Zones' WKT and change the central_meridian to 12.

Comment: This proj string made the trick. I am very thankful and I suggest you give it as an answer so that I can mark it as the proper one.

Comment: In any case I think it would be very beneficial for everyone starting out on using geopandas and related tools if we can put together an explanation on how to read this XML and get the info that is really needed.

Comment: To facilitate the task I have indented the XML for better readability. I will put here in comments what I got from my own research, but I expect this can be improved and I will be glad to read a full answer.

Comment: First of all I noted that the juice is really in the `<gml:definedByConversion>` tag. The part preceding it seems to be a definition of a "starting" CRS given in `<gml:baseCRS>`. The starting one is the EPSG [4326](https://epsg.io/4326) which is like the proj string `+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs `. This can be obtained at the link for [4326](https://epsg.io/4326). Some part of the "base" is not clear to me why is referred to as `6402` or `9901` or `9902` as these, unlike 4326, are not EPSG specifications for a full CRS, they seem to be related to definition of the rotational ellipsoid.

Comment: Other numerical codes are not intelligible to me, except for the fact the tags also have clear text between them, so I can easily guess what they are supposed to mean. Some definitions are helpful, e.g. googling `EPSG::9102` it seems to be the EPSG way to say "degrees" for angles. Anyways, this base reference is the same as the `XML` for `4326`, which can be read [here](https://epsg.io/4326.xml)

Comment: The real juice is in the `<gml:definedByConversion>` and in particular the `gml:usesMethod xlink:href="urn:ogc:def:method:EPSG::9807"/>`, which refers to a coordinates transformation described [here](http://geotiff.maptools.org/proj_list/transverse_mercator.html) in the clearest way (the [9807-method](https://epsg.io/9807-method) page from epsg.io is very obscure and should point to a human readable explanation of the method, as it is only a machine can get it)

Comment: Finally the transformation has 5 parameters: Latitude of natural origin; Longitude of natural origin; Scale factor at natural origin; False Easting; False Northing. These are contained in the XML in tags and are expressed in units of measure given by the property `uom`, e.g. `uom="urn:ogc:def:uom:EPSG::9102"` for degrees. This seems to be only part that went into @FSimardGIS proj string, and I would like to ask why the rest is irrelevant (in particular the part that is written after this in the `<gml:usesCartesianCS>` tag.

Comment: Finally, I'd like to ask if there is a way (possibly in python) to read all this tag, possibly getting it from the gml file itself after I opened it via `ogr.Open`, to let the machine figure this proj string from the XML, which seems a pretty obvious thing to demand a computer code to do.

Comment: Thanks for all the explanations.

Comment: The gml file contains more info like the axes names, units, names of GCS, associated ellipsoid parameters, etc. The BaseCRS section is important because it contains the info about the GCS (WGS84), in other words, which datum is used. The CartesianCS section contains info about the cartesian axes and their names, units, etc. but since these are the default values in proj for transverse Mercator, I did not need to specify all of them. Proj does lose some of the info, but all the necessary info to perform the conversion is there.

Comment: I am not an expert in Geopandas and GML, and I don't know if there is any other way to read the crs definition, but I'll post my proj string as an answer. If you ever find other relevant info you can always answer your own question, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CRS described in your file has essentially the same definition as UTM, but with the central meridian at 12, halfway between zones 32 and 33. So one possible solution is to build a custom string, like a proj string:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=12 +k=0.9996 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

and set this as the CRS of the layer.

Or with a WKT, take any one of the WGS84 UTM Zones' WKT and change the central_meridian to 12 and adapt the WKT:

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 32.5",
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",12],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
AXIS["Easting",EAST],
AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]
```

The meaning of the EPSG codes for the different parameters can be verified on [epsg.org](https://epsg.org/home.html) by searching for the code and choosing the appropriate tab corresponding to the category of the parameter in question.